# Run the service, which continued to work after the Clean Master and rebooting

Tags: android, service

I have service which do something after a certain period of time. It must continue to work after exitting from my app and restart after rebotting device.
I tried to write something like:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

but then the service does not start.

This is my service example:

```
public class GetTextService extends IntentService {
public static final String TAG = "testing_intent_service";
private static final int LONG_INTERVAL = 1000 * 10; //10 seconds

private static Context mContext;

private static int debug_i = 0;

public GetTextService() {
    super(GetTextService.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean isNetworkAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    Log.d(TAG, debug_i + "");
    debug_i++;
    if (!isNetworkAvailable) return;
    //TODO check changes on the site
}

public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn) {
    mContext = context;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, GetTextService.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, i, 0);

    if (isOn) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), LONG_INTERVAL, pi);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        pi.cancel();
    }
}
```

}

And here so I run service:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (PrefsManager.isFirstLaunch()) {//my custom helper class
            GetTextService.setServiceAlarm(this, true);
        }
    }
```

**UPD:** I used BroadcastReceiver which starts service every time after boot. As I see, it works clearly.

Comment: Did you get solution to run service after running clean Master?